# SQL Split field results into two based in value grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data that looks something like the following in Microsoft SQL-Server.

```
|** ITEM **|**              DESCRIPTION                 **|** CODE **| 
1000            Dummy Description for Item 1000               500
1000            Dummy Description for Item 1000               500
1000            Dummy Description for Item 1000               500
1000            Dummy Description for Item 1000               200
1000            Dummy Description for Item 1000               200
1001            Dummy Description for Item 1001               200
1001            Dummy Description for Item 1001               200
1001            Dummy Description for Item 1001               500
1001            Dummy Description for Item 1001               200
1001            Dummy Description for Item 1001               200
```

I would like to group the ITEM values together and then split the CODE field into two showing the count of CODE = 500 and 200 for each item. which would result in something like this...

```
|** ITEM **|**              DESCRIPTION                 **|** 500_CODE **| ** 200_CODE **|
    1000            Dummy Description for Item 1000              3              2
    1001            Dummy Description for Item 1001              4              1
```

Comment: GROUP BY item and description, use two SUM's (with case code = 500 and case code = 200 respectively).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
  select item,
         description,
         sum(case code when 200 then 1 else 0 end) two_hundreds,
         sum(case code when 500 then 1 else 0 end) five_hundreds
    from Table1
group by item, 
         description
```

You can check the demo in [SQLFiddler here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c358/8)

Comment: Thank you mucio for the answer and fiddle example

Comment: I think in your query above,if you use code instead of  description in group by then query would be more efficient .

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you a count for every code in the group,

```
SELECT
      [Item],
      [Description],
      [Code],
      COUNT(*) [Count]
  FROM
      [Table1]
  GROUP BY
      [Item],
      [Description],
      [Code];
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c358/12)

This may be sufficient for your needs, if your really want to transpose the totals to columns you can use [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx),

```
SELECT
      [Item],
      [Description],
      [200] [200_Code]
      [500] [500_Code]
  FROM
(SELECT
      [Item],
      [Description],
      [Code]
  FROM
      [Table1]) [Source]
PIVOT
(
   COUNT([Code]) FOR [Code] IN ([200], [500])
) [Pivot];
```

[See Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1c358/17)